# Yocto recipe is not installing files to the rootfs

Tags: qt, raspberry-pi, embedded-linux, yocto, yocto-recipe

I am creating linux image to run qt application on raspberry pi 3 using yocto. And I have used recipe to install the example app but bitbake doesn't install it to the rootfs.

So I was following some tutorial and the recipe I have used to compile and install the app was as following :

```
SUMMARY = "Simple Qt5 Quick application"
SECTION = "examples"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"
# I want to make sure these get installed too.
DEPENDS += "qtbase qtdeclarative qtquickcontrols2"
SRCREV = "${AUTOREV}"
SRC_URI = "git://github.com/shigmas/BasicQuick.git"
S = "${WORKDIR}/git"
require recipes-qt/qt5/qt5.inc

do_install() {
      install -d ${D}${bindir}
      install -m 0755 BasicQuick ${D}${bindir}
}

FILES_${PN} += " ${bindir}/BasicQuick"
inherit qmake5
```

I have added the package to image install variable too

now the image is generated without any errors and I can find basicquick in the manifest but when I access the rootfs I don't find the app anywhere is there any solution please ?